# IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, lcd, smbus

I tried to connect the LCD display and display the text, but an error occurred.
The LCD driver is OK, and the smbus and I2C tools are also installed correctly. But I wonder why it does not work.
help.

```
# demo_lcd.py

# Simple string program. Writes and updates strings.
# Demo program for the I2C 16x2 Display from Ryanteck.uk
# Created by Matthew Timmons-Brown for The Raspberry Pi Guy YouTube channel

# Import necessary libraries for communication and display use
import lcddriver
import time

# Load the driver and set it to "display"
# If you use something from the driver library use the "display." prefix first
display = lcddriver.lcd()

# Main body of code
try:
    while True:
        # Remember that your sentences can only be 16 characters long!
        print("Writing to display")
        display.lcd_display_string("Greetings Human!", 1) # Write line of text to first line of display
        display.lcd_display_string("Demo Pi Guy code", 2) # Write line of text to second line of display
        time.sleep(2)                                     # Give time for the message to be read
        display.lcd_display_string("I am a display!", 1)  # Refresh the first line of display with a different message
        time.sleep(2)                                     # Give time for the message to be read
        display.lcd_clear()                               # Clear the display of any data
        time.sleep(2)                                     # Give time for the message to be read

except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    print("Cleaning up!")
    display.lcd_clear()
```

---

Comment: Please add the complete traceback.